# Count number of rows in group even if there is zero?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a relation `collab(a1, a2)` with rows

(a1, a2)

```
1, 2
1, 3
1, 3
2, 4
```

and another relation `ident(a1)`
with rows

(a1)

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
```

Then I can I, for each value of `a1` in `ident`, extract `a1` and the count number of `a2`s that are matched with this particular value of `a1`?

Thus, I want the result
(a1, num_a2)

```
1, 2
2, 1
3, 0
4, 0
```

Comment: I guess your count value for 1 should return 3.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement correct, this following query should help you getting your required output-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=54f7fb0ebd5f999f2d91354b8ab836f1)

```
SELECT a1, count(a11)
FROM
(
    SELECT table_2.a1, table_1.a1 a11
    FROM table_2
    LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_2.a1 = table_1.a1
)A
GROUP BY a1
```

As @GMB said, you no sub query is required as directly this can be achieved as below-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=daaefdcd04c50e696d567df68c91a0ff)

```
SELECT table_2.a1, COUNT(table_1.a1)
FROM table_2
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_2.a1 = table_1.a1
GROUP BY table_2.a1
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB, I have added the query without sub query as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if I understood correctly. But here´s my little contribution:

You can use the function "COALESCE" to replace missing values with a zero. In this case you select your ID list from the table IDENT and left join the table collab with the number count (distinct in your case, as you want unique numbers, like in your output) and replace all NA´s with zeros:

> SELECT t1.a1, COALESCE(t2.NUMBER, 0)
>
> FROM( SELECT a1  FROM ident) t1
>
> LEFT JOIN
>
> ( SELECT a1, COUNT (DISTINCT a2) as N FROM collab GROUP BY a1 ) t2